# AWS Database Backup RDS to S3 By Crontab (Cron Job)

Tags: php, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cron

I want to create database backup on daily bases using cron job.

I have created one batch file for database backup. Below is batch file code.

```
#!/bin/bash
SQLDUMP="$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M').sql.gz"

echo "Creating backup of database to $SQLDUMP"  
mysqldump --host 'myhost.com' -u 'root' -p 'password' --databases 'test' | gzip -9 > $SQLDUMP

echo "Dump Zipped up"

echo "Uploading zipped dump to the Amazon S3 bucket…"  

s3cmd put $BACKUPNAME s3://example.com/dbbackup/$BACKUPNAME 

echo "Removing the backup file $SQLDUMP"  
rm $BACKUPNAME

echo "Done"
```

But database backup not storage on S3.

File Path : var/app/current/app/sqlbackup.sh

Set for 5 hrs in Crontab : * 5 * * * /bin/sh /var/app/current/app/sqlbackup.sh

Comment: This is not a batch file. You should change the tag to `bash` from `batch-file`.

Comment: Have you run `aws configure` from the cli and set up your ssh user to have access to S3?

Comment: You haven't told us what's wrong. Is cron failing to run the script? Is mysqldump failing? Is the s3cmd upload failing?

Comment: @jarmod I am getting 
/var/app/current/sqlbackup.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found
 reating backup of database to 201709191440.sql.gz

/var/app/current/sqlbackup.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found
Dump Zipped up
/var/app/current/sqlbackup.sh: line 9: $'\r': command not found
Uploading zipped dump to the Amazon S3 bucket…
/var/app/current/sqlbackup.sh: line 11: s3cmd: command not found
/var/app/current/sqlbackup.sh: line 12: $'\r': command not found
 emoving the backup file 201709191440.sql.gz

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you have not setup for s3cmd package in your AWS server. So please check all below setup. So I think you have helpful points:

```
Setup :- 1 
On CentOS/RHEL: # yum install s3cmd
On Ubuntu/Debian: $ sudo apt-get install s3cmd
On SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11:
    # zypper addrepo http://s3tools.org/repo/SLE_11/s3tools.repo
    # zypper install s3cmd

Setup :- 2
Install Latest s3cmd using Source 

$ wget http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/s3tools/s3cmd/1.6.1/s3cmd-1.6.1.tar.gz
$ tar xzf s3cmd-1.6.1.tar.gz

Now install it using below command with source files.
$ cd s3cmd-1.6.1
$ sudo python setup.py install

Configure s3cmd Environment
# s3cmd --configure
```

Enter new values or accept defaults in brackets with Enter.Refer to user manual for detailed description of all options.

For more details Please check below link :- https://tecadmin.net/install-s3cmd-manage-amazon-s3-buckets/#

Batch file check :- File name sqlbackup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
SQLDUMP="$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M').sql.gz"
SQLDUMPPATH="/backupdb/$SQLDUMP"
mysqldump -pPASSWORD -u root -h HOST.amazonaws.com database_name | gzip -9 > $SQLDUMPPATH
s3cmd put $SQLDUMPPATH s3://S3NAME/dbbackup/$SQLDUMP
echo "Removing the backup file $SQLDUMP"  
rm $SQLDUMPPATH
echo "WooHoo! All done"
```

Comment: This helped me . ..Thank you.

Comment: Welcome , Mittul

Comment: Are Mittul sir g , aisa nai hai ;)